# loading huge data from NOSQL/CSV - Python

Tags: python, database, csv, nosql

Am new to NOSQL DB. In our project, we load huge data from CSV/NOSQL DB via python for doing various analysis.

Can someone suggest some approach for loading Huge datasets of Columns/Rows from CSV as well as from NOSQL DB to python to do various analysis on the loaded data.

Because, opening the raw CSV file in excel with more than a million rows is impossible.

Preferably an open source is appreciated.

Thanks,
David

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/ for data analysis.

Comment: Nice link. Thanks a lot!